# $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and surjective , X is complete if and only if Y is complete.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,\rho)$ and $(Y,\rho')$ be metric spaces. Assume $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous on $X$  and surjective. Are these statements true:

1. If $(X,\rho)$ complete then $(Y,\rho')$ is complete
2. If $(Y,\rho')$ complete then $(X,\rho)$ is complete?

Comment: For the second question think about $Y$ being a singleton.

Comment: and at the same time consider any $X$ that is not complete :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y=[1,\infty)$ and $X=(0,1]$

consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ continuous on $X$ and surjective

$Y$ is complete being a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ but not $X$